# Rating Bar view only on android

Tags: android, readonly, ratingbar

I'm trying to create an android application where one of the activities has a rating bar. Is there a way to make a Rating Bar a view only so that the user will not be able to modify it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, just call setIsIndicator(true)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setIsIndicator(boolean)